How to split table in excel using power query? Error when using Table.SelectRows in Power Query on Excel: 'Added Index' wasn't recognized
I'm attempting to split a table in Excel based on rows using Power Query. Specifically, I want to create a separate table for "NON-CURRENT ASSETS".
my data
I've been following a tutorial on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FB5Zs29A8fw&t=145s
At one point in the process, I used the following expression:

Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each[2021]= null)

However, upon executing this step, I received the following error message:

Expression.Error: The name 'Added Index' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Can someone please explain why this error occurred and suggest potential solutions to resolve it?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

The first thing after the ( should be the name of the step you want to apply the process to.  Looking at your image, that is #"SplitLocation".  Easiest thing to do is just take your data and use the drop down arrow atop the column to [x] the results you want
"

Upon further review, I realized that I accidentally deleted a column after creating the index column (according to the YouTube tutorial, I should have proceeded directly to SplitLocation). Thank you for your response.

After some troubleshooting, I realized that ensuring the step before 'SplitLocation' is 'Added Index' resolves the problem effectively. This ensures the sequence of operations aligns correctly with my workflow.
